# git build number c#

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to embed `git describe`-generated version info into `AssemblyInfo.cs` plus some label within ASP.NET website.

I already tried using [git-vs-versionino](https://github.com/jasperboot/git-vs-versioninfo) but this assumes Git executable on `PATH`. However default install of `msysgit` on Windows does not set this up; it uses git bash. This caused problems.

Now I am looking for a way to utilize [`libgit2sharp`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/) library (for zero external dependencies) to use as build number generator. However this library has no `describe` command...

Thanks!

Comment: Would leaving a copy of the Git executable in a non-default installation path work?

Comment: You need to get all msys libs with it; which means putting it in repository.

Answer (score 1):

`git-describe` is a UI feature that nobody has implemented in the library or bindings yet (or at least nobody's contributed it), but you can do it yourself fairly easily.

You get a list of the tags and what commits they point to, do a walk down the commits and count how many steps it took to get to a commit that you have in the list you built. This already gives you the information you need. If the steps were zero, then your description would be the tag name only; otherwise you append the number of steps and the current commit's id to it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a work in progress libgit2 pull request that proposes an implementation of git-describe functionalities.

See **[#1066](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1066)** for more information.

It's not finished yet. Make sure to subscribe to it in order to be notified of its future progress.

Once it's done, it should be quite easy to bind it and make it available through LibGit2Sharp.